# Android Build Targets

Tags: android, build, target

I have experience in java and I was thinking in starting developing for Android now. Trouble is I have an Android Phone with 2.1-update1 and an Eee Pad Transfomer with 3.1 and I would like to build applications that could work on both devices.

When creating a project in eclipse, I need to choose the Build target, but I can only choose one, so do I choose one that is compatible with both devices or I need to separate projects for different build targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set up Eclipse to compile with Android 2.1, then it will run on 3.1 too. Most Android API's are backward compatible.

Comment: What about if compile level (project build target) is 3.1, targetSdkVersion is 3.1 and minSdkVersion is 2.1 will it work on Android 2.1 device?

Answer (score 2):

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="7" android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
```

In Manifest file, set the "uses-sdk" version to API number matching your Version 2.1 (it's 7, Honeycomb 3.1 is 12)

Set minSdkVersin to whatever you desire (API level 3 is OLD Android 1.5)
Do not set maximum if you want to support future updates of Honeycomb, ignore Warning related to this at build time.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Answer (score 1):

Just Use the lower version as target.